# Module Broken Link – installation fails

Tags: 9

The ›Broken Link‹ module yields an ›unexpected error‹ during installation. Afterwards everything *seems* to be fine and the module is listed as installed, but a node Administration->Configuration->System->Broken Link is missing.

What am I missing?

The error seems to be:

```
Type    php
Date    Thursday, February 17, 2022 - 10:39
User    me
Location    https://mydomain.at/admin/modules
Referrer    https://mydomain.at/admin/modules
Message     Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "user.private_tempstore". in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 156 of /var/www/drupal-9.3.6/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
Severity    Error
Hostname    myhost
Operations
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a bug report for a contributed module and needs to be handled in the issue queue on Drupal.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a problem with a module, the first place to look is the [module's issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/broken_link).

Sometimes there are a lot of issues to search through, but in this case, the error is described in the [first issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/broken_link/issues/3165809).

You can download the patch in the issue and apply it to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! (And especially for the ›issue‹-hint! Can't yet upvote.)